# Brightness control not working with Ubuntu 22.04 on Lenovo X1 Yoga (OLED display)

Tags: lenovo, brightness

Using the brightness control Fn+F5 and Fn+F6 is showing a bar that changes the status, but the screen brightness does not change on Ubuntu 22.04 on Lenovo X1 Yoga Gen 2. I can see the brightness status-bar, so apparently it recognizes the command, but the screen brightness does not change.

I tried editing`/etc/default/grub`, but it did not work:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux thinkpad-acpi.brightness_enable=1"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=none acpi_osi=Linux"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=intel acpi_osi=Linux"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Windows"
```

then I tried to installing the tool brighness-control, that cannot change the brightness either.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
sudo apt install brightness-controller
```

Maybe the common solutions are not working with an OLED screen?

Then I tried `sudo apt install brightnessctl`:

```
sudo brightnessctl set 10%+
sudo brightnessctl set 10%-
```

I get the message that

```
Device 'intel_backlight' of class 'backlight':
Current brightness: 1060 (100%)
```

and the value in
`/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/` changes, but the screen brighness does not change at all.

```
xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --brightness 1  # no dimming
```

Also has no effect.

Comment: With apologies on behalf of the community, it looks like your question was spammed by a trio of bots that are posting multiple AI-generated answers on questions. Unfortunately, the majority of the Moderators on Stack Exchange sites (including Ask Ubuntu) are on strike *primarily* because the parent company has reduced their ability to remove these bogus answers.  We're hoping that things get back to normal shortly, but in the meantime, we're having to deal with stuff like this.

Comment: At some point, the AI-generated answers below will be removed, so it's possible they'll already be gone by the time you check back in here. In that case, you'll just be thoroughly confused on what I'm talking about ;-).

Comment: Weird, I already addressed that these approaches did not work anyway. Are people actually reading the question before they post AI answers? They having fun functioning as a ChatGPT interface? Hope the answers are at least based on GPT-4!

Comment: They definitely aren't reading the questions (or answers) in this case; just spamming every 3-4 minutes.  One person, almost certainly, running the three accounts (nine total now - 6 others have been "retired") :-/

Comment: What people waste their time and effort on...

Comment: Agreed - And then I go and waste my time cleaning up after them.  I've now come across more than 3,000 GPT/AI generated answers here, on Stack Overflow, and a few other SE sites. :-/

Comment: The fight for attention. We would be better off, if more people would do nothing.

Comment: The Yoga X1 2gen is now garbage. There is no operating system anymore that supports it and which itself is supported. W11 does not run officially, W10 is outdated, and no Linux distro supports all features, brightness, fingerprint reader, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
https://github.com/udifuchs/icc-brightness
```

This solution make the Fn+F5 and Fn+F6 (in my case) somewhat work. It is not perfect, but at least something. Sometimes the brighness gets stuck at some level.

Comment: Frustratingly, trying this with `./icc-brightness watch` gave me `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight'`.  Installing this does nothing for the brightness controls at all, unless I have misunderstood how to use it.